# Getting htaccess to scan a subdirectory based upon prefix (subdomain)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

This is an odd one, and I appreciate any help that you can send.  I have a domain name (domain.com) and there will eventually be any number of subdomains (subdomain.domain.com).  If the URL has a prefix indicating a subdomain, htaccess invisibly redirects to a subdirectory, prepares the actual request, and appends the subdomain's name as a parameter in the query string.  So far this is working perfectly as long as I don't request an actual file.  htaccess is obviously scanning the root directory for the requested file and coming up empty.  Is there a way to prepare a rewrite rule that returns a file from the appropriate subdirectory IF a subdomain prefix is included?  I would also want to pass along an attached query string (including the subdomain's value).

```
    > Example 1: http://www.domain.com processes http://www.domain.com
    > Example 2: http://subdomain.domain.com processes http://www.domain.com/subdirectory/index.php?key1=subdomain
    > Example 3: http://subdomain.domain.com/contact processes http://www.domain.com/subdirectory/index.php?key1=subdomain&key2=contact
    > Example 4: http://subdomain.domain.com/somepage.php?name=foo processes http://www.domain.com/subdirectory/somepage.php?name=foo&key1=subdomain
```

The code below can handle examples 1 through 3, but not #4.

```
# Cleanup
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]


# Client
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|css|js|php|xml|html)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^$ subdirectory/index.php?key1=%1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|css|js|php|xml|html)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^/home$ subdirectory/index.php?key1=%1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|css|js|php|xml|html)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_+?&-]+)$ subdirectory/index.php?key1=%1&key2=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|css|js|php|xml|html)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_+?&-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+?&-]+)$ subdirectory/index.php?key1=%1&key2=$1&key3=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|png|css|js|php|xml|html)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^%{REQUEST_URI}$ subdirectory$1&key1=%1 [L,QSA]
```